# $\beta$-mercaptoethanol molarity

Tags: experimental-chemistry, concentration

I'm writing up a practical and $\beta$-mercaptoethanol was used, with no concentration given. I've found I don't need the BME molarity since I'm giving percentage (v/v) concentration, however I'm slightly confused as to why there are different values for its concentration.

[Sigma-Aldrich provide BME concentration 14.3 M](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/m6250) (pure liquid), yet the [openwetware.org protocol for SDS sample buffers](http://openwetware.org/wiki/SDS_sample_buffer) gives a molarity of 14.7 M. I can't see precisely how this is derived from its density, or why there'd be different molarities floating around.

Not that it matters for my writing here, but since I don't know the molarity I'm just a bit puzzled now as to what it may have actually been, and would rather understand now than have to work it out further down the line. Any answers greatly appreciated!

Comment: @immx Your question is similar to this post http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/717/whats-the-weight-of-1-liter-of-x-hci/719#719 .

Comment: @Eka I'm sorry but I don't agree... I appreciate the "homework policy" you're directing me to; this isn't "homework" and I'm not asking for an answer on a plate.

I think I should have mentioned that I don't see how molarity can be greater than the molarity of a pure liquid.

Comment: @Eka I followed the link to the post you mentioned and read your answer.  You might consider revising it (see the [comment I left under the question] (http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/717/whats-the-weight-of-1-liter-of-x-hci/719#comment21321_717).)

Answer (score 5):

From the Aldrich data:
 $\rho = 1.114\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{mL}}\ \text{at}\ 25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$

Converted to a more convenient unit:
 $\rho = 1.114\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{mL}} \cdot \frac {1000\ \mathrm{mL}}{1\ \mathrm{L}} = 1114\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{L}}$

Given the molar mass (also from Aldrich) of:
 $M = 78.13\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{mol}}$

We learn that one liter has:
 $1114\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{L}} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{mol}}{78.13 \ \mathrm{g}} = \frac{1114}{78.13}\ \frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{L}} = 14.26\ \frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{L}}$

I can't speak to why your other source has a different number.